# Keep the instance attached to ELB when autoscaling is scaling in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have a use-case to keep the instances selected to terminate during a scale-in event in attached to ELB. I know that it has a connection drain timeout with max value of 1 hour but thats too short. I have Lifecycle hooks in the instance to send heartbeat so instance will not be removed from the ASG but it will be removed from the ELB after an hour.

Is there a way to keep the instance attached to the ELB until heartbeat stops.
Actual use-case is I have a video bridge server in the Autoscaling group so in a scale-in case I do not want the users to be disconnected, instead move the instance to maintenance mode (new calls won't be scheduled) and wait until running calls become zero and finally remove from both ASG and ELB.

Comment: Does you instance maintain an active connection with users during this disconnection period? It is highly unlikely you could keep a connection like this open through a web browser, or are you doing TCP-level routing? Do you use sticky sessions to keep communication open to the same ELB? If requests take this long to process, you really should move to a queuing request model rather than keeping a connection open for over an hour.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein a "video bridge server" sounds like a streaming application rather than long-running request/response.  This doesn't seem like a perfect fit for what ALG+ELB is designed for... something with behavior that is more customizable than ELB, like HAProxy, might be better though you then have to manage instance joining and leaving since the system can't do it for you.

Comment: @johnRotenstein you are right I was mistaken that we have an ELB fronting the bridges. So this is not an issue anymore. Sorry to waste your time but Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question if it is not something that can benefit other readers.